# Relation between Wireless Power Transfer, Wireless Information Transfer and the definition of sum rate

Tags: digital-communications

I read this paper [Charge-then-Forward: Wireless Powered Communication for Multiuser Relay Networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8396282/)
 ,and it said it on the second page ,and I don't really understand why is the theory ,the author said, right.

> the time of WPT, Wireless Power Transfer, should be as small as possible so that the time for wireless information transmission (WIT) can be maximized for sum-rate maximization

Does anyone know the definition of sum-rate in formula type and the relation of WPT and WIT? I think I can really understand reason if I know these first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sum-rate" is just the sum of all rates of communications happening in a network.

The statement is pretty self-evident: The more time your nodes can communicate, the more data they can transfer.

Comment: but it said the time of WPT should be smaller,not longer

Comment: Wpt limits wit, which is what you want to maximize

Comment: i think the author should want to maximize WPT

Comment: but hasn't the rate  been divided by time?if so,why it will become higher when the time become longer?

Comment: aim is to transfer Information, not power. So you maximize the time you transfer information, which inherently limits the time you sent power. I really don't understand you confusion!

Comment: maximize the time you transfer information, which inherently limits the time you sent power  i don't understand this sentence means,can you explain it more?

Comment: You have time. You can, in this time, **either** send power **or** send data. You want to send data. So you spend as little time as possible sending power, and as much time as possible sending data. (I'm really confused about what's difficult about that concept.)